# Is an order two homeomorphism of $S^{1}$ orientation reversing?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $f:S^{1}\to S^{1}$ be a non-trivial homeomorphism. Suppose we have $f\circ f = id$. Can we say that $f$ has to be orientation reversing?

I think this is true. But I couldn't come up with a proof.

Thanks in advance for any kind of help!

Comment: Consider $x \to x + \frac{1}{2}$ on $S^1 = \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, or more simply just $x \to x$.

Comment: No. I don't want to consider the trivial homemorphism! I have edited that.

Comment: If you do not want to consider the trivial automorphism, you can consider the other example @anomaly gave you...

Comment: Could you not just have two rotations, i.e. $z \in S^{1}$, take $f(z) = ze^{\pi i}$

Comment: Yeah $f(z)=-z$ will do!

Comment: Bit $f(z)=-z$ reverses the orientation...

Comment: The first example given by @anomaly is simply the rotation by 180º.

Comment: But isn't rotation by $180^{o}$ same as f taking $z$ to $-z$?

Comment: An orientation on $S^1$ is just a continuous choice of nonzero tangent vector at each point. How does the $1$-dimensional tangent bundle of $S^1$ behave under $Df$?

Comment: ...and, more to the point, consider the maps $x \to x + \frac{1}{2}$ and $x \to 1 - x$ on $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wrong and there are infinitely many counter examples,  eg any conjugate ($ gfg^{-1} $) of the $180º $-rotation by any homeomorphism $ g $ ($ g $ itself does not have to respect the orientation).

What is interesting now is that the result becomes true (and not so hard to prove) if you replace the circle by the real line! In particular it is true on the circle if you ask additionally that the homeomorphism has a fixed point.